# google map is not displayed properly

Tags: android, google-maps

[image: google_map]

Hi, im testing the google map api,  but the map is incomplete. I`ve tested it on a device also and the result is the same. What is wrong??

This effect starts when i add some attributes to the map, for example:

```
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        // enable Street view by default
         mapView.setStreetView(true);
```

If nothing is added, the map is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turned out that this effect appeared only if i set:

```
mapView.setStreetView(true);
```

But not any other attribute, so if someone comes to this problem thats the solution, just delete this line. Maybe the problem is appearing because the default view of the map is StreetView.